# Grant Select To Synonym For Specified Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to restrict a user's select access to a synonym. Consider the following below:

```
CREATE USER Test_User WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE SYNONYM S_TEST FOR dbo.Items;

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.S_TEST (Id, [Name]) TO Test_User;
```

I get an error:

> Msg 1020, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
>   Sub-entity lists (such as column or security expressions)
>   cannot be specified for entity-level permissions.

But if I change it to use dbo.Items directly then it works:

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Items (Id, [Name]) TO Test_User;
```

How can I restrict the SELECT on a synonym for a specified user? Is this possible? If no, are there any alternatives?

Comment: I would try it with an alias (as) not sure if it would work xD Probably `GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Items (Id, [Name]) TO Test_User as S_TEST;`

Comment: I really need a solution that'll work with synonyms. I use synonyms to create an abstraction between the test and production environment. Current system access external database so it's for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"How can I restrict the SELECT on a synonym for a specified user? "* You can't. A Synonym is just an alternative name for an object. The check to see if the object even exists is deferred till runtime when referencing the `SYNONYM` *not* when it's created. For example `CREATE SYNONYM dbo.MySynonym FOR MadeUp.TableObject;` *will* create the synonym even though the reference object doesn't exist.

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.MySynonym FOR MadeUp.TableObject;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.MySynonym; --fails
GO

DROP SYNONYM dbo.MySynonym;
GO
```

All the permissions need to be set up the object that the Synonym references, not the synonym itself.

Comment: This are my thoughts too just that I'm compelled to try. Anyhow, can you explain the error message I got when I tried to specify the columns for the synonym?

Comment: Synonyms don't have columns, @jegtugado , so you can't specify columns (sub-entity) levels objects for its permissions.